# How to extract pattern from text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to extract only dni from text field called "Document"

i have some text like this in my database:

```
Document varchar(max):

"Lorem ipsum 12345678-0 dolor 2345678-k sit amet, consectetur $2000000 adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

I wanna get only dni:

```
12345678-0
2345678-k
```

and ignore: $2000000

Comment: I am not sure you've provided enough information. Is there a pattern in similar entries? Going off this alone unfortunately makes your question a bit vague

Comment: You really need a regex find/replace here, and SQL Server does not support that out of the box.  Honestly, this operation isn't really what databases are mainly designed to be doing.

Comment: all records (more than 1000) have the same structure. Text, investment value and the identity document of the person (DNI).

and I only want to extract the DNI from said text

Comment: [Follow this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vz7Xw6/1) to see what a regex based approach might be able to do here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen exactly as your demo is what I'm looking for. How can I do the sql or maybe it is possible in python?

Comment: Not possible in SQL Server, without using a custom UDF or some sort of plugin.  Yes possible in Python, but since you already asked for SQL Server, I don't know how much more attention your question is going to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one SQL Approach.

If SQL 2016+... use string_split()

You may have to tweak the `WHERE` to be more inline with your actual needs.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Document varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Lorem ipsum 12345678-0 dolor 2345678-k sit amet, consectetur $2000000 adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Document,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                Where B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') like '[0-9]%-%'
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       12345678-0
1   2       2345678-k
```

Comment: @RaulEscalona Happy to help

Answer (score -1):

not sure what DNI stands for but assuming it's just a string representing number with a dash combination, you could use split string + like expression.

```
select *
from (
SELECT 
  value, 
    case 
      when value LIKE '%[0-9]%' and value like '%-%' then 1 
      else 0 
    end as dni
FROM   STRING_SPLIT ('Lorem ipsum 12345678-0 dolor 2345678-k sit amet, consectetur $2000000 adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.', ' ') 
) t
where dni = 1
```